# How to Update some data in a table from another table in MS Access 2007 by checking a value from the second one?

Tags: ms-access-2007

i want to update some data from a table (ehraz) in MS_Access 2007 by another table's data by checking this condition : if tableA.siba=Table2.siba then update Table1.field1 by Table2.Field2.
i use this t-sql command in sql server and works :

```
 update ehraz set 
 ehraz.B_CODEMELI =bn.B_CodeMelli ,
 ehraz.B_NAME =ltrim(rtrim(cast(bn.B_Name as nvarchar(20)))) ,
 ehraz.B_FAMILY =ltrim(rtrim(cast (bn.B_Family as nvarchar(30)))) ,
 ehraz.B_FATHER_N = ltrim(rtrim(cast(bn.B_Father_N as nvarchar(20)))),
 ehraz.B_SHENAS =ltrim(rtrim(bn.B_Shenas)) ,
 ehraz.B_TAVALOD = ltrim(rtrim(cast(bn.B_Tavalod as nvarchar(15)))),
 ehraz.B_MOSHTARI = ltrim(rtrim(cast(bn.B_Moshtari as nvarchar(20)))) ,
 ehraz.B_BARNO = ltrim(rtrim(cast(bn.B_Brno as nvarchar(10)))) ,
 ehraz.CLOS = ltrim(rtrim(cast(bn.CLOS as nvarchar(5))))
 from bn_data bn
 where ehraz.siba = bn.Siba
```

how can i do this in MS-Access 2007? this query did't works in ms access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
update ehraz 
inner join bn_data bn
on ehraz.siba = bn.Siba
set 
ehraz.B_CODEMELI = bn.B_CodeMelli,
ehraz.B_NAME = Trim(CStr(bn.B_Name)),
ehraz.B_FAMILY = Trim(CStr(bn.B_Family)),
ehraz.B_FATHER_N = Trim(CStr(bn.B_Father_N)),
ehraz.B_SHENAS = Trim(CStr(bn.B_Shenas)),
ehraz.B_TAVALOD = Trim(CStr(bn.B_Tavalod)),
ehraz.B_MOSHTARI = Trim(CStr(bn.B_Moshtari)),
ehraz.B_BARNO = Trim(CStr(bn.B_Brno)),
ehraz.CLOS = Trim(CStr(bn.CLOS));
```

Answer (score 0):

this query will not work in MS-Access because some of the keywords that are used in the query are not supported by MS-Access like the cast function is not supported in MS-Access. Instead Use `CStr` function for type conversion into text Format and `CInt` function to type conversion in Number format....

try replacing these keywords and let me know if this helps.